# Copying tables from databases to a database in AWS in simplest and most reliable way

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, devops

I have some tables from three databases that I want to copy their data to another database in an automated way and these data are quite large. My servers are running on AWS. What is the simplest and most reliable way to do so?

**Edit**
I want them to stay on-sync (automation process as DevOps engineer)

The databases are all MySQL and all moved between AWS EC2. The data is in range between 100GiB and 200GiB
Currently, Maxwell to take the data from the tables then moved to Kafka and then a script written in Java to feed the other database.

Comment: is this a one time effort or do you need them to stay in-sync over time? What database engines are involved?

Comment: Please Edit your question to include more information. For example: Are the databases running on Amazon RDS, or on EC2 instances? What database engines are they (eg MySQL, SQL Server, PostgreSQL, etc)? What do you mean by "quite large"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Malek, how fast does the data change in these tables?  What is your destination database for consolidating this data?

Comment: @gsteiner the data changes momently as they are recording orders. The destination data bases is MySQL same as the source ones.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use AWS Database Migration Service (DMS) to replicate tables from each source into a single target.  You would have a single target endpoint and three source endpoints.  You would have three replication tasks that would take data from each source and put it into your target.  DMS can keep data in sync via ongoing replication.  Be sure to read up on the documentation before proceeding as it isn't the most intuitive service to use, but it should be able to do what you are asking.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/Welcome.html